# Error 137 (net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED): Unknown error

Tags: networking, firefox, google-chrome

That's what I'm getting. I have an Internet connection. Most sites load, some don't. There is no scheme like, a specific site doesn't load or it happens at a certain time. A random site at a random time will have this problem and I have to reload the page 100 times before I can visit it. The same happens in Firefox.

So far I restarted my router, put the Ethernet cable into another router slot, restarted the PC and reinstalled my browsers. The problem is still there and happening. I have no viruses, at least Malwareantibytes and antivirus software tells me that.

I don't really want to reinstall Windows 8. Anyone have an idea what is causing this?

Comment: Change preferred DNS, for example use Google's one: `8.8.8.8`, `8.8.4.4`

Comment: Just did this. When I won't have any error in the next 1-2 hours I will let you know that this worked!

Comment: your ISP's DNS is crapping put. @gronostaj's suggestion should help you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FireFox as your primary Internet Proxy, do these steps:
1. Reset your security protocol to "nil" (you can change it back later)
2, clear all cache and set same for max 1024 mg, [no less or more, important!]
3. Reboot PC in safe mode
4. clear IE's cache
5. Reboot, then
6. Restart FireFox

Your problem should clear.  Demonstrable error and per-configured error in cache designed like normal .exe program but actually virus recognised by Norton Anti-Virus programs as being Trojan.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer, but I'm not using Firefox. Also, I think the problem lays in the router, since, now I have a totally new computer, with new sotware/new network card and the problem is still there!